# Python ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_iso'

Tags: python, module, pip, conda

How to install `_iso` python module through pip or conda?
I have a python file in which they are import this _iso and i am not getting any method to install this _iso file.

I am using python 3.8 and conda version 4.8.2

Comment: Where did you get the file? Are you sure the original user didn't have more local files?

Comment: I think yes no local files,
Anyway i comment that module.

Comment: if it is local python files then i think error should not come while importing as i have downloaded all the files.